# Online reference for bridge between $\mathbb C$ and $\mathbb F$

Tags: perverse-sheaves, reference-request

I am looking for a text which

1) Explains how to deduce statements about perverse sheaves on complex geometry from analogous statements in positive characteristic. For example the last chapter "De F a C" of BBD: Faisceaux pervers, Astérisque 100 would be ideal.

2) Is available online, this point is crucial.

So the perfect answer to this question would be a way to obtain an electronic copy of Astérisque 100 though I suspect it is not available online.

Comment: http://www.math.harvard.edu/~gaitsgde/grad_2009/BBD.djvu

Comment: Why is it so essential that it be available online?  I mean, why use an inferior text just to avoid a trip to the library?

Comment: @Alex, why don't you make that an answer so the OP can accept it?

Comment: @ Alex: Make this an answer and I will gladly accept it. 
@ Andy Putman: There are two reasons: 1. It is not allowed to borrow it form the library and library will be out of range for some time. 2. There will be a seminar about it, so there are several people interested in reading it, but there is only one copy in the library.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it has been answered in a comment.